# ArcGIS routing with LatLng WGS84

Tags: arcgis-android

I have wrote code based on the guide at: https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/guide/find-a-route.htm

I am able to make API calls to find a route with just a start and end point as shown in these 2 lines:

```
    Stop stop1 = new Stop(new Point(-13046294.924, 4036100.529, SpatialReferences.getWebMercator()));
    Stop stop2 = new Stop(new Point(-13046094.899, 4036273.038, SpatialReferences.getWebMercator()));
```

but I want my program to work exclusively in LatLng. I am able to get the results back in LatLng by setting the parameter: `mRouteParameters.setOutputSpatialReference(SpatialReferences.getWgs84());` but if I do:

```
    Stop stop1 = new Stop(new Point(32.863797, -117.205879, SpatialReferences.getWgs84() ));
    Stop stop2 = new Stop(new Point(32.902620, -117.150526, SpatialReferences.getWgs84() ));
```

.... using LatLng to find a route in California it returns an exception when I call: `RouteResult routeResult = routeResultFuture.get();`

The exception is:`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.esri.arcgisruntime.io.JsonEmbeddedException: Unable to complete operation.`

**So I guess this means there is something wrong with my query to the API but what? How do I correctly give the waypoints using LatLng Points?**

Edit to add full code:

```
public class ArcGisRoutePlanner extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String LOG_TAG = Utility.APP_TAG + ArcGisRoutePlanner.class.getSimpleName();
private MapView mMapView;
private RouteTask mRouteTask;
private ListenableFuture<RouteParameters> mRouteParametersFuture;
private RouteParameters mRouteParameters;
private boolean mRouteNotLoaded = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arc_gis_route_planner);

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.Type.STREETS, 34.056295, -117.195800, 16);
    mMapView.setMap(map);
    mMapView.addDrawStatusChangedListener(new DrawStatusChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void drawStatusChanged(DrawStatusChangedEvent drawStatusChangedEvent) {
            if (!mRouteNotLoaded) startRouteTask();
        }
    });
}

private void startRouteTask() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startRouteTask");
    mRouteNotLoaded = true;
    // Create the route task
    String server = "http://utility.arcgis.com/usrsvcs/appservices/XXXXXXXXXX/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World";
    mRouteTask = new RouteTask(server);

    // Load the route task
    mRouteTask.loadAsync();
    mRouteTask.addDoneLoadingListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mRouteTask DoneLoadingListener");
            try {
                mRouteTask.getLoadError();// returns load error, if any
                LoadStatus ls = mRouteTask.getLoadStatus(); // returns load status
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Load status is: " + ls.name() );
                loadRouteParams();
            }
            catch (ArcGISRuntimeException e) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In catch - Load error: " + e.getAdditionalMessage() );
            }
        }
    });
}

private void loadRouteParams() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "loadRouteParams");
    mRouteParametersFuture = mRouteTask.createDefaultParametersAsync();

    // In a non-UI thread, get the route parameters
    mRouteParametersFuture.addDoneListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mRouteParameters = mRouteParametersFuture.get();

                // update properties of route parameters
                mRouteParameters.setReturnDirections(true);
                mRouteParameters.setReturnRoutes(true);
                mRouteParameters.setOutputSpatialReference(SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
                specifyStopsAndBarriers();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "loadRouteParams catch block");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void specifyStopsAndBarriers() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "specifyStopsAndBarriers");
    // create stops first
    List<Stop> stops = new ArrayList<>();
    //Stop stop1 = new Stop(new Point(-13046294.924, 4036100.529, SpatialReferences.getWebMercator())); //works
    //Stop stop2 = new Stop(new Point(-13046094.899, 4036273.038, SpatialReferences.getWebMercator())); //works

    Stop stop1 = new Stop(new Point(32.863797, -117.205879, SpatialReferences.getWgs84() )); //does not work
    Stop stop2 = new Stop(new Point(32.902620, -117.150526, SpatialReferences.getWgs84() )); //does not work
    //32.863797, -117.205879
    //32.902620, -117.150526


    stops.add(stop1);
    stops.add(stop2);

    // add stops to routeParameters
    mRouteParameters.getStops().addAll(stops);

    // create barriers
    List<PointBarrier> pointBarriers = new ArrayList<>();
    pointBarriers.add(new PointBarrier(new Point(-13044448.387907, 4037674.739924, SpatialReferences.getWebMercator())));

    // add barriers to routeParameters
    //mRouteParameters.getPointBarriers().addAll(pointBarriers);
    executeRouteTask();
}

private void executeRouteTask() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "executeRouteTask");
    final ListenableFuture<RouteResult> routeResultFuture = mRouteTask.solveRouteAsync(mRouteParameters);
    routeResultFuture.addDoneListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (routeResultFuture.isDone()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "routeResultFeature is done");
                try {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DoneListener inside executeRouteTask");
                    RouteResult routeResult = routeResultFuture.get();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RouteResult language: " + routeResult.getDirectionsLanguage());


                    // Get one of the routes in the result
                    Route route = routeResult.getRoutes().get(0);

                    // Parse route
                    Polyline polyline = route.getRouteGeometry();
                    ImmutablePartCollection partCollection = polyline.getParts();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "partCollection size is: " + partCollection.size() );

                    Iterable<Point> points = partCollection.getPartsAsPoints();
                    for (Point p : points ) {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Point:" + p.getX() + " , " + p.getY() );
                    }

                    // Add GraphicsOverlay to the map view
                    GraphicsOverlay graphicsOverlay = new GraphicsOverlay();
                    mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().add(graphicsOverlay);

                    // Add the route to a graphics overlay
                    int routeSymbolSize = 10;
                    SimpleLineSymbol routeSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.YELLOW, routeSymbolSize);
                    Graphic routeGraphic = new Graphic(route.getRouteGeometry(), routeSymbol);
                    graphicsOverlay.getGraphics().add(routeGraphic);
                }
                catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Result catch: " + e.getCause());
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "routeResultFeature not done");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPause");
    mMapView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.resume();
}
}
```